# How can I make the before hook execute just once?

Tags: rspec, capybara

In my current code I have the `visit 'root'` and `login` command executing before each spec is run. How can I have it execute just once so I can speedup the tests? Currently to work around this I was adding several specs into one spec.

It's also a clientside JS app so the app has to be built on every visit call. Logins can be slow as well. Once the app is loaded then the rest can be really snappy.

```
feature "Edit Project Page" do

  context "logged in user with one project" do

    # would like this to execute once for the context
    before() do
      visit root_path      # slow, whole app has to rebuild
      login_user           # also slow
      sleep 1
      @user_id = user_id()
      create_project
    end

    scenario "foo" do
      #...
      page.should have_content "foo"
    end 

    scenario "bar" do
      #...
      page.should have_content "bar"
    end 

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting it seems like `before(:all)` will run the setup only once (I was assuming no param would do this).